# CUDA: Confused by the CUDA Memory Model and Memory Allocation

Tags: memory, cuda

For anyone who was confused as I was in the future, TLDR:

- Malloc (when called from a CPU thread) allocates memory on the host. You already know this, nothing different here.
- Malloc (when called from a GPGPU [device] thread) allocates memory on the device, or GPGPU memory. This is essentially what you want for allocating memory when inside a CUDA kernel.
- CudaMalloc is a bit strange in that it allocates memory on the device, but is called from (say int main()) a **host function**. So this is called from a thread executing on the CPU, but allocates memory on the device or GPGPU. I don't fully understand what the pointers point to when this happens yet.

## Question

I am new to CUDA. I am currently confused by the way in which memory allocation works in CUDA.

There are lots of combinations of questions I could ask to gain an in-depth understanding, but to keep things simple I shall just ask the 1 question.

I am parallelizing a code which I wrote to work with C++11 threads. (Actually, it's already parallelized, I am just moving from CPU threads to GPU ones.)

I have a cuda kernel function. It looks like this:

```
__global__
void cuda_kernel(int N)
{
    std::vector<double> vec;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++ i) vec.push_back(0.0);
}
```

However this is not allowed.

---

Side note:

I don't know why. *I don't **really** care why either but if you would like to tell me then I will be happy to read the information you present. It's always good to know why but **this is not my main question***. (Quite often I encounter the problem where someone answers the question they wanted to see rather than the actual question asked, so this is why I raise this comment. Please "read the full question" is what my highschool math teacher often used to say! But you probably don't care about that.)

Note that some people appear to be confused as to why this code was included. This is just to demonstrate that I realize that I can't do this. I originally wrote code with `std::vector`, but now I realize that won't work on a CUDA system, I am no longer using C++ and vectors, I am using C and (hopefully when I understand it better) "old school style" memory allocation - which I now believe involves either `cudaMalloc()` or `malloc()` - but there is confusion about which one to use.

---

## Back to Question

I don't know how use dynamic memory within a CUDA kernel function / a thread running on a CUDA GPGPU device. This is what I would like to know:

How do I...

- Allocate Memory on a GPGPU device to be used by a GPGPU.
- Free / deallocate this memory after I am done with it.
- Access for read/write of this memory.

## Don't worry about data races because...

(Here is an analogous process which explains why.)

My parallelized process is what I call intrinsically parallelized or trivially parallelizable. I is impossible to get data races / memory corruptions because all blocks of memory are independent of all others. Think of this as being similar to the vector addition problem. All components are independent when adding vec A = B + C, hence the procedure is trivially paralleizable.

Note again that **I am not doing anything related to vectors what so ever**. This is just an example to help explain approximately what my code does. No it doesn't add vectors together, but it does work in a similar manner in that there is no cross-communication between elements of block-allocated memory. By this I mean, no processors read and write to more than their own uniquely allocated area of memory. If you still don't understand then just ignore the possibility of data corruption or data races. They cannot occur.

## Back to Question

If someone could help me with this I would be grateful. I might post a more complex question at a later date when my understanding improves. Thank you.

## Note:

I removed the C++ tag and replaced it with C because this is really a C question not a C++ one.

## Note 2:

This is an extremely narrow question. I want to know how to do 3 things only. Those are:

- Allocate Memory on a GPGPU device to be used by a GPGPU.
- Free / deallocate this memory after I am done with it.
- Access for read/write of this memory.

Comment: your question is *very* broad; you should read the [CUDA documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#device-memory) and *then* post a question if things are still unclear

Comment: Read section B.18 of the CUDA programming guide, try it out, and if you still don't know your way around after that, ask a focused question.

Comment: @m.s. I've read sections of it and found it confusing.

Comment: Regarding the edit: how can a C question involve `std::vector`?

Comment: @Angew `std::vector` is not involved.

Comment: Perhaps you'd want to remove `std::vector` from your question then, if it's not involved?

Comment: @Angew Well no, because I am demonstrating what I am not allowed to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91745/discussion-between-user3728501-and-angew).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be overlooking the more typical option: don't write kernels that need to allocate memory. Instead, the caller should *pass memory into the kernel*; e.g. passing in a pointer obtained by `CudaMalloc` or `thrust::device_vector`.

This memory, of course, needs to be shared amongst all of the threads; make this buffer have enough for everybody, and then each thread uses its thread and block indices to determine which part of the buffer belongs to it.

For example,

```
__global__
void kernel(int N, double *vec_all)
{
    int index = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    double *vec = vec_all + N * index;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) { vec[i] = 0.0; }
}
```

Comment: Okay so the votes are in favour of `cudaMalloc` over `malloc`... What is the difference between these things?

Comment: @user3728501: If you run `malloc` on the host, you get a pointer to host memory, and so you can't pass it into the kernel for the device to use. But if you `CudaMalloc` on the host, you get a pointer to device memory that you can pass into the kernel.

Comment: Okay thanks, yes this agrees with the comments on the answer below. I am no longer confused.

Comment: What happens if I dereference a pointer created using `cudaMalloc`? (On a host thread?)

Comment: @user3728501 UB (Undefined Behaviour). Most likely a crash.

Answer (score 3):

Device code does not support allocating memory through the C++ standard library (such as `std::vector`). If you want to do dynamic memory allocation in your kernels, you have to use `malloc` and `free`:

```
__global__
void cuda_kernel(int N)
{
    double *vec = malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++ i) vec[i] = 0.0;
    free(vec);
}
```

It is possible to use `malloc` in one kernel and `free` in a different kernel—the memory persists between calls. The allocations by `malloc` in device code come from a device heap, which is a portion of device memory. More memory can be available to `cudaMalloc` (callable from host) than to `malloc` (callable from device).

Comment: Surely `malloc` and `free` allocates memory in my (host/CPU) memory rather than in my (device/GPU) memory?

Comment: @user3728501 OK, I now don't believe you've ever read B.18 of the Cuda Programming guide. Quoting page 131: "The CUDA in-kernel `malloc()` function allocates at least size bytes from the device
heap..." Please explain how you can claim this allocates from host memory.

Comment: I am confused because it uses the same named function as that for allocating host memory.

Comment: For example, what in the hell is `cudaMalloc` if `malloc` allocates on the **device**?!

Comment: This I have just encountered.

Answer (score 1):

First, the reason you kernel is not working is that you are using the C++ standard library in it. CUDA C does not support this. Thus you cannot use things like std::vector or other STL types.

The question you are asking are VERY basic and you should really be able to find this information easily. Have tried looking it up or did you come straight here?

Look at the [CUDA C programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide). It contains examples doing almost exactly what you are asking.

Comment: As stated, the answer is incorrect. CUDA C supports a large part of C++; most of the *language* is supported, actually (templates, virtual functions, member functions etc. are fair game). It's the C++ *standard library* which is not supported.

Comment: Aha - here is someone who didn't read the question. But yes I did look online, and I got confused because the material encountered was not clear, hence the question.

Comment: I did read the question, and the CUDA C programming guide has an example doing a vector add which was what you were asking. It has even been pointed to directly by m.s. The example shows you specifically how you do the three things you listed. `CudaMalloc` is used to allocate memory on the GPU. `CudeMemCpy` is used to read and write to that memory. `CudaFree` is used to free the memory. I would think that answers your questions quite sufficiently.

Comment: @Taus And `malloc` can be used to allocate memory from the device heap in device code.

Comment: @Taus What you've said contradicts other posts. Firstly someone tells me to use `malloc` now you are saying that is not correct and I should use `cudaMalloc`? Which is it to be?

Comment: When inside a Kernel executing on the device you use `malloc` and use it like regular memory.. When on the host you use `CudaMalloc` and access it with `CudaMemCpy`. Be aware however, when accessing through `CudaMemCpy` you are transfering between host and device which incurs quite a bit of overhead.

Comment: @Taus Ah, right - now we are getting somewhere. Thanks for this. So I would use `cudaMalloc()` from say a main function running on a CPU, and then I would use `malloc()` for something inside a CUDA process / thread / some function executing on CUDA hardware?

Comment: Yes.  But as Hurkyl pointed out the usual way is to do things is by allocating from the using `CudaMalloc` on the host and simply passing in pointers to the allocated memory.